# Splitting a string by value between quotation marks in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I'm reading in a file in Java and want to split each line by the value inside quotation marks. For example, a line would be...

"100","this, is","a","test"

I would like the array to look like..

```
[0] = 100
[1] = this, is
[2] = a
[3] = test
```

I normally split by comma, but since some of the fields include a comma (position 1 in the example above) it's not really suitable.

Thanks.

Comment: The String.split(String regex) method uses a regular expression as the argument, so just use a regex that matches `"something"` not sure off the top of my head but someone will give u the answer soon enough

Comment: remove first and last `"` character and then split it on `","`

Comment: yeah I'm a little confused about the commas in his example, I didn't see it 1st

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

```
    String yourString = "\"100\",\"this, is\",\"a\",\"test\"";
    String[] array = yourString.split(",\"");
    for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++)
        array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Finally **array** variable will be the desired array

**Output:**

```
    100
    this, is
    a
    test
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split it the following way:

```
String input = "\"100\",\"this, is\",\"a\",\"test\"";
for (String s:input.split("\"(,\")*")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Output**

```
100
this, is
a
test
```

**Note**
  The first array element will be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one simple way:

```
String example = "\"test1, test2\",\"test3\"";
int quote1, quote2 = -1;
while((quote2 != example.length() - 1) && quote1 = example.indexOf("\"", quote2 + 1) != -1) {
  quote2 = example.indexOf("\"", quote1 + 1);
  String sub = example.substring(quote1 + 1, quote2); // will be the text in your quotes
}
```

Comment: With a more telling name than "a" and an example String, so that the snippet is runnable and so that you can provide the example output, this would be perfect ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using a regex.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String s = "\"100\",\"this, is\",\"a\",\"test\"";
    String arr[] = s.split(Pattern.quote("\"\\w\"")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Output:

```
["100","this, is","a","test"]
```

What it does is matches:

```
 \" -> start by a "
  \\w -> has a word character
  \" -> finish by a "
```

I don't know what kind of values you have, but you can modify it as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, but works:

```
    String s = "\"100\",\"this, is\",\"a\",\"test\"";
    StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder(s);
    sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
    String [] buffer= sb.toString().split("\",\"");
    for(String r : buffer)
        System.out.println(r); code here
```

Comment: instead converting your string to StringBuilder, you can use substring method on string

Comment: I though of that, but decided it was easier to understand with an explicit method like `deleteCharAt`